# Query to join two table and sort the data array using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, join

I need one help.I have two table i need to join two table and display them inside user's table.I am explaining my table structure below.

> db_summary:

```
id     member_id     hit_type    device_type

1       20            1              IOS

2        12           2              IOS

3       20            3             Android

4       14           4              Android

5       12           3              IOS

6       14            5              IOS
```

From the above table the `hit_type` column value is linked to the following table's `type` column.

> db_hit_type:

```
id      name      type

1       Page        1

2       Map         2

3       Gallery     3

4      Phone        4

5      Web          5
```

From the `db_summary` table if `hit_type=1` means its a `page hit` which is defined in second table. Here i need to fetch both table data by joining and sort them as per `member id` to display in following user's ui table.

```
sl no     member   page Hit   Map Hit   Gallery Hit  Phone Hit  WebHit TOTAL
```

i need to fill the above table by using the db data.suppose for member id `20` how many nos of `page hit,Map hit......`  and total nos of hit.I need to fetch all data and sort them as per user's table structure.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or when you want to view the resulting data, but at some point you will need to run a query counting each type of hit per user from the db_summary table, then updating the user table with the resulting data.

You could do something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `db_summary` WHERE `member_id` = :member");
$stmt->bindParam(':member', $memberid);
$stmt->execute();

$hit = array(0,0,0,0,0);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::ASSOC))
{
    ++$hit[$row['hit_type']-1];
}

echo 'Type 1 Hits: ', $hit[0];
echo 'Type 2 Hits: ', $hit[1];
echo 'Type 3 Hits: ', $hit[2];
echo 'Type 4 Hits: ', $hit[3];
echo 'Type 5 Hits: ', $hit[4];
```

If you need to update all members, you can wrap all of that into a loop that loops through each member id.

Comment: i need actually how many nos of `page hit,map hit......` in each member id and the total hit.This is my basic requirement.This seems little bit complecate.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get both table data

SELECT * FROM db_summary AS ds, db_hit_type AS dht WHERE ds.hit_type = dht.type GROUP BY ds.member_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbs.*,dbht.name,dbht.id as dbHitId
FROM db_summary as dbs
LEFT JOIN db_hit_type as dbht
ON dbs.hit_type=dbht.type
ORDER BY dbs.member_id
```